# MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015): SSD replacement

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd

I would like to replace my 256GB storage with a drive having more space, and *not less efficient* in terms of read/write speed. I was thinking about something like `Samsung Pro` drives with M.2 interface. But I am not sure if MacBook uses standard interface for this purpose.

So my question is, which drives/memory chips are compatible with my laptop model? Which hardware interface should I look for?

Also I guess that I need some specific toolkit to replace SSD, right? At least, to open laptop's back lid.

Comment: Does [this page](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-how-to-upgrade-ssd-storage.html) answer your questions?

Comment: @nekomatic Thank you for the link. Yes, that was helpful. Then could you tell me please, am I right that [this guy](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-787) (Transcend JetDrive 820) should be compatible?

Comment: @devforfu it should: at this page: https://www.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrive_pcie there is the compatibility list. To be 100% sure, instead of the model description cross check with the Mac model Identifier ("in the About This Mac window, click System Report. In the System Information window that opens, find Model Identifier in the Hardware Overview section.") In your case it's probably 11,4 or 11,5

Comment: @GioValerio Yes, you're right - it is 11,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @nekomatic and @GioValerio. I guess that one of `JetDrive 820` drives should be sufficient for my purposes.